# How to allow access to Underlying Connection?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-batch

I have defined a datasource in my baseContext.xml

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" autowire-candidate="default">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"></property>
    <property name="url" value=""></property>
    <property name="username" value=""></property>
    <property name="password" value=""></property>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value=""></property>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="tue"></property>
    <property name="validationQuery" value=""></property>
</bean>
```

This datasource is writing a clob value to a oracle db. And while doing so it throws this error

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   OracleLobCreator needs to work on [oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection], not
>   on [org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection]:specify a
>   corresponding NativeJdbcExtractor; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection cannot be cast to
>   oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

I tried to set this property **"accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed"** as true but it said cannot instantiate the bean, property does not exist.

Other solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239392/jdbc-connection-leak-on-jdbc-pool-when-using-aq) asked to use native jdbc extractor but i dont know how to specify that in this bean

I am using Spring Batch running on tomcat and i just specify this datasource when i configure the JobRepository

```
<batch:job-repository data-source="datasource" id="jobrepo" transaction-manager="transacMnager" table-prefix="" isolation-level-for-create="READ_COMMITTED"></batch:job-repository>
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: did you try to use this method: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#getConnection()?

Comment: I am using Spring batch and i just point to this datasource when i specify the JobRepository, Essentially, i dont have corresponding java code when i explicitly get the connection, the Spring Batch Framework does that. So any configuration i need to do would be here, the place where i am specifying the datasource bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the lobHandler in the jobRepository 
FOr example:

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="transacMnager" />
   <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="READ_COMMITTED" />
   <property name="lobHandler">
      <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
         <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor">
            <bean class="yourCorrectJdbcExtractor" />
         </property>
      </bean>
   </property>
</bean>
```

I hope it can be useful

Angelo

Comment: i also had to set "allowAccessToUnderlyingConnection" as true when defining the Datasource. thanks for the help :)